# Running Flask celery and gunicorn from a single docker container

Tags: python, docker, flask, celery, gunicorn

I am trying to run both flask app with celery and gunicorn in same docker container. I am usinf supervisord for this. Gunicorn is executed from `docker-compose.yml` as

```
services:
  web:
    container_name: "flask"
    build: ./
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - DEPLOYMENT_TYPE=production
      - FLASK_APP=app/main.py
      - FLASK_DEBUG=1
      - MONGODB_DATABASE=testdb
      - MONGODB_USERNAME=testuser
      - MONGODB_PASSWORD=testuser
      - MONGODB_HOSTNAME=mongo
    command: gunicorn app.main:app --workers 1 --name main --reload -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --preload
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - mongo
    links:
      - mongo
```

In the supervisord.conf, celery is setup

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:celeryworker]
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
command=/opt/venv/bin/celery -A app.routes.celery_tasks.celery worker --loglevel=info -B -s app/celerybeat-schedule
```

The supervisor is executed from dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
LABEL maintainer="nebu"
ENV GROUP_ID=1000 \
    USER_ID=1000
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates supervisor procps cron vim python3.8-venv python3-gdbm 
WORKDIR /app
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/opt/venv
RUN python3 -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV
ENV PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"
RUN ["python", "-m", "pip", "install", "--upgrade", "pip", "wheel"]
RUN apt-get install -y  python3-wheel
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN ["python", "-m", "pip", "install", "--no-cache-dir", "--upgrade", "-r", "/app/requirements.txt"]
COPY ./app /app
RUN ["mkdir", "-p","/var/log/supervisor"]
COPY ./app/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

But when i bring all the containers up, celery and beat are not coming up. So I entered the shell of flask app container and executed `/usr/bin/supervisord`, then the celery worker is brought up without any error. How is it possible to bring both gunicorn and celery worker-beat together from the same docker container.

**Update**

when I used the below supervisord.conf, nginx is not coming up. Its showing error

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:celeryworker]
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
command=/opt/venv/bin/celery -A app.routes.celery_tasks.celery worker --loglevel=info -B -s app/celerybeat-schedule

[program:myproject_gunicorn]
user=root
command=gunicorn app.main:app --workers 1 --name main --reload -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --preload
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

**Error**

```
nginx exited with code 1
nginx            | 2022/04/09 09:41:56 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "web" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/app.conf:8
nginx            | nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "web" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/app.conf:8
nginx exited with code 1
nginx            | 2022/04/09 09:41:59 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "web" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/app.conf:8
nginx            | nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "web" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/app.conf:8
```

Comment: Typically a Docker container only runs a single process; for a setup like this you'd run multiple containers, each with the same `image:` (or `build:`) but a different `command:`.  Can you get all of the parts running without involving supervisord?

Comment: @David Maze I am running in separate containers. But the image created will be have 2GB size each. So i thought of running celery and gunicorn in the same container. Tried with supervisor too. But nginx is throwing error

Comment: Since they have the same `image:` the additional containers won't actually take up any extra space; they all share the same underlying physical storage for the one image.  (Or if they have the same `build:`, because of Docker layer caching, they will build the same image with the same image ID.)

Comment: So it means that if I build two container from same image, it wont take 2 GB each and just single 2GB will be used ? Is that correct. But when i check by `docker image ls` its showing two images with 2GB each. That makes me confusing.

Comment: That output includes shared layers and `df` will have a more correct output.  This approach should work and (in spite of a longer `docker-compose.yml`) is usually simpler and more manageable than bringing in supervisord; you might ask a new question if you have a setup that's apparently creating multiple large images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]` in dockerfile and `command: gunicorn app.main:app --workers 1 --name main --reload -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --preload` in docker-compose.yml have a conflict.

In fact, `command` in docker-compose.yml will override `CMD` in dockerfile. That is why only gunicorn is up.

My suggestion: add gunicorn related stuff to supervisord.conf and remove `command` in docker-compose.yml.

In this way, supervisor will bring both gunicorn and celery up.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This worked. Hope you will upvote the question also :)